# onSelectAll option is not working in react-bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to add select all property to `multiselect`, I added `onSelectAll` prop but I cant see select all option.

See below code.

```
<Multiselect 
     data={this.props.list} 
     multiple 
     ref="industry" 
     onSelectAll 
     onChange={this.handleDropdown.bind(this, 'industry')} 
     buttonText={function(options, select) { 
                     return 'Industry ('+ options.length+')'; }} 
/>
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `includeSelectAllOption`. This is described in the original plugin [here](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

```
<Multiselect 
 data={this.props.list} 
 includeSelectAllOption
 multiple 
 ref="industry" 
 onSelectAll={this.selectAll} 
 onChange={this.handleDropdown.bind(this, 'industry')} 
 buttonText={function(options, select) { 
                 return 'Industry ('+ options.length+')'; }}
```

/>

Your `onSelectAll` should be a function. This function will be called when the user selects `Select all` from the dropdown